# Eclipse - YAML error : Expected a 'String' but got a 'Mapping' node

Tags: java, eclipse, yaml, metadata

I am adding my own custom properties in a YAML file.  The existing Spring properties work fine but my own custom ones become underlined in yellow, which creates a warning in the project.  There is an option to add to the metadata but once I do that the warning becomes this error :

```
Expected a 'String' but got a 'Mapping' node
```

This is what I am adding :

```
com:
  foo:
    bar:
      foobar:
        someString: hello
        someBoolean: true
```

Where is this YAML metadata stored and how can I tell it that com is not a String and is really a mapping node?

******EDIT******

I found the metadata is stored in the META-INF folder in a file called additional-spring-configuration-metadata.json.  If I tell Eclipse to generate the metadata for `com` for example, this gets added to said file :

```
{"properties": [{
  "name": "com",
  "type": "java.lang.String",
  "description": "A description for 'com'"
}]}
```

What do you have to change `java.lang.String` to in order for `com` to accept `foo` and so on?

Comment: What are you using to edit/validate the YAML?

Comment: I'm using the YAML editor 1.6.2 i got from Eclipse Marketplace

Comment: I just found a file called "/additional-spring-configuration-metadata.json" in the META-INF folder that contains what I need.  What do I need to change java.lang.String to for it to know that it is a mapping node?

Comment: in properties change "name" to "com.foo" and "type" to (fully qualified class name)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hello I am the maintainer of the mentioned eclipse plugin (https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/yaml-editor)

Normally when you have got problems with yaml editor plugin it's recommended to create an issue for this at https://github.com/de-jcup/eclipse-yaml-editor/issues

I tried out your given example and there is no error appearing with current version 1.6.2. Are you sure you are really using Yaml-Editor to open your file and not another installed editor ? To ensure you should try out to open your file by context action (e.g. inside project explorer) at your file and `Open with -> Yaml Editor`.

If there are still problems, please create an issue at github and add the link to this question.

[image: Screenshot-Yaml-Editor-with-Example]

Comment: You are right, the YAML editor install had not completed all the way so it was still being opened with the default Eclipse editor which was underlining the properties with no metadata in yellow and offering to create it.  Once created, my problem arose where package names were being created as String.  I do not have the yellow underline anymore but I would still like to know how to document the metadata properly.

Comment: Yaml Editor plugin has - at least at the moment - no special meta data treatment. It just takes yaml files (of any kind) , uses snake parser to parse the content. If there are parse errors those will appear in UI (see also https://github.com/de-jcup/eclipse-yaml-editor/wiki).